# getting error while calling the smart contract functions through frontend (react)

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to connect my smart contract with my react frontend , but the problem is each and everytime I call the function of smart contract through fronted its throwing the error of call revert exception. Smart contract is working properly , succesfully passed all the testcases.

this is the frontend code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import Abi from './abi.json';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
  const [Contract, setContract] = useState(null);
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
  const [Balance, setBalance] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

    const loadProvider = async () => {
      if (provider) {
        window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', () => {
          window.location.reload();
        });

        window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', () => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const address = await signer.getAddress();
        setAccount(address);
        const contractAddress = '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3';

        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Abi.abi, signer);
        setContract(contract);
        setProvider(provider);



      } else {
        console.error('Metamask is not installed');
      }
    };

    provider && loadProvider();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(Contract);
    const bal = await Contract.getBalance(account);
    setBalance(bal.toString());
    console.log(Balance)
    try {
      const name = await Contract.mint(20);
      setToken(name);
      console.log(name);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error calling name():', error);
    }
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar account={account} />
      <h1>Account: {account}</h1>
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <p>how are you {Balance}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is smart contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNDEFINED
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "./IERC20.sol";

contract ERC20 is IERC20 {
    uint public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    string public name = "MKrushna";
    string public symbol = "MK";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    

    //stacking var

    mapping (address=>uint) public stackedBalance;
    mapping (address =>uint) public stakeStartTime;
    uint public  stakingDuration  = 1 weeks;
    uint public rewardRate = 10;

    event Staked(address indexed user, uint amount);
    event Unstaked(address indexed user, uint amount);

    function getName() external view returns (string memory) {
  return name;
}
    function getSymbol() external view returns (string memory) {
  return symbol;
}
    function getBalance(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
  return balanceOf[_user];
}

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balanceOf[recipient] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool) {
        allowance[sender][msg.sender] -= amount;
        balanceOf[sender] -= amount;
        balanceOf[recipient] += amount;
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function mint(uint amount) external {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        totalSupply += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, amount);
    }

    //stack function

function stake(uint amount) external  {
    require(amount>0 , "amount should be greater than zero");
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >=0, "not sufficient balance");

    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balanceOf[address(this)]+= amount;

    stackedBalance[msg.sender] += amount;
    stakeStartTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;

    emit Staked(msg.sender , amount);

}

function unstake(uint amount) external {
    require(amount >0 , "Amount is must br greater >0");
    require(stackedBalance[msg.sender] >=amount, "not enough staked balance");


    uint reward = calculateReward(msg.sender);

    stackedBalance[msg.sender] -= amount;
    stakeStartTime[msg.sender] = 0;

    balanceOf[address(this)] -= amount;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount+ reward;

    emit Unstaked(msg.sender, amount);


}
   function calculateReward(address user) internal view  returns (uint){
       if(stakeStartTime[user] ==0){
           return 0;
       }

       uint stakingTime = block.timestamp-stakeStartTime[user];

       uint reward = (stackedBalance[user] *rewardRate * stakingTime) /(stakingDuration * 100);
        return reward;
   }
}
```

console.log(contract) -> also giving the all the functions and related data in the console but each public data has empty string.

Answer (score 0):

your `mint` function is emitting `Transfer` event

```
function mint(uint amount) external {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        totalSupply += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, amount);
    }
```

but you did not define `Transfer` event